# Uses Tabs in Blade with Same Route, Different Methods in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using tabs but same controller, different methods. How to return values to different views with same route?

In /users, get value from db via BuyerSellerController@buyers method for **buyer**.

```
Route::get('users','BuyerSellerController@buyers');
```

In /users as well, get value from db via BuyerSellerController@sellers method for **seller**.

```
Route::get('users','BuyerSellerController@sellers');
```

//BuyerSellerController

```
public function buyers()
{
    $buyerSeller = DB::table('buyerseller')
        ->where('buyerseller','=','Buyer')
        ->pluck('id');

    $buyers = DB::table('users')
        ->where('buyerseller','=',$buyerSeller)
        ->get();

    return View::make('pages.users')->with('buyers', $buyers);
}

public function sellers()
{
    $buyerSeller = DB::table('buyerseller')
        ->where('buyerseller','=','Seller')
        ->pluck('id');

    $sellers = DB::table('users')
        ->where('buyerseller','=',$buyerSeller)
        ->get();

    return View::make('pages.users')->with('sellers', $sellers);
}
```

//users.blade.php
Then I got this error:

```
Undefined variable: sellers (View: ...)
```

Comment: You have to use different URIs. How would the application otherwise know which controller method to call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compact saved my life! :D

```
public function index()
{
    /* buyers */
    $buyerSeller = DB::table('buyerseller')
        ->where('buyerseller','=','Buyer')
        ->pluck('id');

    $buyers = DB::table('users')
        ->where('buyerseller','=',$buyerSeller)
        ->get();


    /* sellers */
    $buyerSeller = DB::table('buyerseller')
        ->where('buyerseller','=','Seller')
        ->pluck('id');

    $sellers = DB::table('users')
        ->where('buyerseller','=',$buyerSeller)
        ->get();

    return View::make('pages.users', compact('buyers', 'sellers'));

}
```